# Resolve multiple objects in angularjs ui-router state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is my code:

```
.state("dashboard.userRoles", {
    url: "/user/:id/roles",
    controller: "userRolesController as vm",
    templateUrl: "app/auth/users/user-roles.html",
    resolve: {
        user: function (userResource, $stateParams) {
            return userResource.get({ id: $stateParams.id }).then(function (res) { return res.data; });
        },
        roles: function($http, $stateParams) {
            var url = appSettings.authApiBaseUrl + "api/accounts/users/" + $stateParams.id + "/roles";
            return $http.get(url).then(function(res) { return res.data; });
        },
        loadMyFiles: function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                name: "app",
                files: [
                    "app/auth/users/userRolesController.js"
                ]
            });
        }
    }
})
```

If I navigate to dashboard.userRole and look in fiddler, I see the request to get the user resource, but not the roles. If I comment out the user: section, I see the request to get the roles in fiddler. Why can't I resolve both? Should I just be sending the id into the controller and get everything there?

I was trying to avoid gathering data in the controller as it should just be the stitching between the view model stuff and the ui. Maybe that doesn't matter? Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit 1:**
Ok, I can change the code to this and see both requests showing in fiddler, and they both return the properly formatted json data:

```
.state("dashboard.userRoles", {
    url: "/user/:id/roles",
    controller: "userRolesController as vm",
    templateUrl: "app/auth/users/user-roles.html",
    resolve: {
        user: function (userResource, $stateParams) {
            return userResource.get({ id: $stateParams.id }).$promise;
        },
        roles: function($http, $stateParams) {
            var url = appSettings.authApiBaseUrl + "api/accounts/users/" + $stateParams.id + "/roles";
            return $http.get(url).then(function(res) { return res.data; }).$promise;
        },
        loadMyFiles: function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                name: "app",
                files: [
                    "app/auth/users/userRolesController.js"
                ]
            });
        }
    }
})
```

However, the roles injected into the controller are always 'undefined'. The user is populated correctly. And the response in fiddler shows the roles that come back, so I'm not sure why they are undefined. Here is the controller code.

```
"use strict";

angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("userRolesController", [
        "user", "roles", function (user, roles) {

            console.log("app.userRolesController.function()");

            var vm = this;
            vm.user = user;
            vm.roles = roles;
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: what is `userResource`? is that a `$resource` object?

Comment: yes, it's a $resource object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [angular-ui-router issue/question](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/77) was helpful. Anyhow, this works!

```
.state("dashboard.userRoles", {
    url: "/user/:id/roles",
    controller: "userRolesController as vm",
    templateUrl: "app/auth/users/user-roles.html",
    resolve: {
        user: function (userResource, $stateParams) {
            return userResource.get({ id: $stateParams.id });
        },
        roles: function($http, $stateParams) {
            var url = appSettings.authApiBaseUrl + "api/accounts/users/" + $stateParams.id + "/roles";
            return $http.get(url);
        },
        loadMyFiles: function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                name: "app",
                files: [
                    "app/auth/users/userRolesController.js"
                ]
            });
        }
    }
})
```

And here is the controller. The .data on roles is important!

```
angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("userRolesController", [
        "user", "roles", function (user, roles) {

            var vm = this;
            vm.user = user;
            vm.roles = roles.data;
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: and if you want the promise returned for `$resource` ...`return userResource.get({ id: $stateParams.id }).$promise`

Comment: How can I use in a state resolve a service which is loaded before to call and use it; sth like this: let's say that in `user` I load my service file with ocLazyLoad and in `roles` I want to use that loaded service? How to wait for lazyload?

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint (or watch) in the Chrome browser (within your angular controller).  And inspect `$state`.  I found my answer to be:

```
  $state.$current.locals.globals.employeeslist
```

Answer (score -1):

Thats pretty weird. Perhaps you could try:

```
.state("dashboard.userRoles", {
    url: "/user/:id/roles",
    controller: "userRolesController as vm",
    templateUrl: "app/auth/users/user-roles.html",
    resolve: {
        // put both in one object
        data: function (userResource, $stateParams, $http) {
            var url = appSettings.authApiBaseUrl + "api/accounts/users/" + $stateParams.id + "/roles";
            return {
                user: userResource.get({ id: $stateParams.id }).then(function (res) { return res.data; });
                roles: $http.get(url).then(function(res) { return res.data; });
            }
        },
        loadMyFiles: function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                name: "app",
                files: [
                    "app/auth/users/userRolesController.js"
                ]
            });
        }
    }
})
```

**Update:**

Solution above doesn't fix the problem. OP has resolved his own issue (See the comments below).

Comment: when I try that only the userResource.get request shows in fiddler. :o(

Comment: Hmm..perhaps this is an issue with fiddler... does the controller receive the data anyway?

Comment: See my edit, I updated the resolve on and see fiddler showing both api requests, both responding with the correct data, however the controller always shows the "roles" data as undefined for some reason.

Comment: Ok so you dont need that `$promise` or the `then()` on the roles request. `$promise` is only used with `$resource` types. By default, I believe `$http.get(url)` returns a promise

Comment: You are correct, I just go it to work based on [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/77).

Comment: Cool beans. I'll just update my answer to direct attention down here.